Implement a function that works the same as str.split method (without using str.split itself, of course)
I tried a code that works for some of the splits. But it keeps failing on the majority of asserts. Can u plese help?
from typing import List
def split(data: str, sep=None, maxsplit=-1):
    empty_str = ""
    my_list = []
    for c in data:
        if c[0] == ',':
            my_list.append(c)
        elif c == ' ' and empty_str != '':
            my_list.append(empty_str)
            empty_str = ''
        else:
            empty_str += c
    if maxsplit == 0:
        return data
    if empty_str:
        my_list.append(empty_str)
    return my_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert split('') == []
    assert split(',123,', sep=',') == ['', '123', '']
    assert split('test') == ['test']
    assert split('Python    2     3', maxsplit=1) == ['Python', '2     3']
    assert split('    test     6    7', maxsplit=1) == ['test', '6    7']
    assert split('    Hi     8    9', maxsplit=0) == ['Hi     8    9']
    assert split('    set   3     4') == ['set', '3', '4']
    assert split('set;:23', sep=';:', maxsplit=0) == ['set;:23']
    assert split('set;:;:23', sep=';:', maxsplit=2) == ['set', '', '23']


why do you have c[0]?

You are not using sep in your function.

regarding c[0] - I'm trying to catch the comas and add them into list

well, how should I use sep?

I really don't understand what you intended to do with if c[0] == ',': my_list.append(c). Please explain step by step what that is supposed to do? There are no comments in your code.

@trincot I`m trying to catch comas with c[0] cause if I don't do it, they are just skipped and that's all

You're doing for c in data. c will be a single character. There's no point in accessing the first character of a single-character string. c is the same as c[0] is the same as c[0][0][0].

@deceze yeah, i tried to catch the first character. Later I planned to add similar code for the last character in a str. But asked if there smarter solution than to write a long if\elif\else...

There are some problems in your code. First, sep is not used in your code; second, only the case of maxsplit==0 is considered. Let's suppose that your assert clauses are right and let's start from the most simple split case: split a string with a separator without considering maxsplit. For example, split "ABC,DEF" with separator "," and get ["ABC", "DEF"]. "ABC" is left of the separator "," and "DEF" is right of the separator ",". A function is created here:
def split_helper(data: str, sep=','):
    if data.find(sep) >= 0:
        left=data[0:data.find(sep)]
        right=data[data.find(sep)+len(sep):len(data)]
    return (left, right)

Then you can use it like:
for substring in split_helper("ABC,DEF", ","):
        print(substring)

the output is as follows.
ABC
DEF

Next, let's consider the default case: split with space ' ', we have the following code to deal with it.
def split_with_space(data: str, maxsplit=math.inf):
    output = []
    temp_str = ""
    split_count = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if(data[i] == ' ') and split_count < maxsplit:
            temp_str = temp_str.lstrip()
            output.append(temp_str)
            temp_str = ""
            split_count+=1
        else:
            temp_str+=data[i]
    temp_str = temp_str.lstrip()
    output.append(temp_str)
    temp_str = ""
    return output

You can use it as follows.
for substring in split_with_space("ABC DEF"):
        print(substring)

the output of the code above is as follows.
ABC
DEF

Absolutely, if you set maxsplit to 0, you'll get:
ABC DEF

Test cases
If you want to check the correctness of the implementation of split function, just compare it with built-in split function.
test_string = ''
assert split(test_string) == test_string.split()
test_string=',123,'
assert split(test_string, sep=',') == test_string.split(sep=',')
test_string='test'
assert split(test_string) == test_string.split()
test_string='Python    2     3'
assert split(test_string, maxsplit=1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=1)
test_string='    test     6    7'
assert split(test_string, maxsplit=1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=1)
test_string='    Hi     8    9'
assert split(test_string, maxsplit=0) == test_string.split(maxsplit=0)
test_string='    set   3     4'
assert split(test_string) == test_string.split()
test_string='set;:23'
assert split(test_string, sep=';:', maxsplit=0) == test_string.split(sep=';:', maxsplit=0)
test_string='set;:;:23'
assert split(test_string, sep=';:', maxsplit=2) == test_string.split(sep=';:', maxsplit=2)

All of the code with test cases:
import math
from typing import Optional

def split_helper(data: str, sep=','):
    if data.find(sep) >= 0:
        left=data[0:data.find(sep)]
        right=data[data.find(sep)+len(sep):len(data)]
    return (left, right)

def split_with_none(data: str, maxsplit=math.inf):
    data = data.lstrip()
    output = []
    temp_str = ""
    split_count = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if(data[i] == ' ') and split_count < maxsplit:
            if temp_str!="":
                temp_str = temp_str.lstrip()
                output.append(temp_str)
                temp_str = ""
                split_count+=1
        else:
            temp_str+=data[i]
    temp_str = temp_str.lstrip()
    if temp_str!='':
        output.append(temp_str)
    temp_str = ""
    return output

def split_with_space(data: str, maxsplit=math.inf):
    output = []
    temp_str = ""
    split_count = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if(data[i] == ' ') and split_count < maxsplit:
            temp_str = temp_str.lstrip()
            output.append(temp_str)
            temp_str = ""
            split_count+=1
        else:
            temp_str+=data[i]
    temp_str = temp_str.lstrip()
    output.append(temp_str)
    temp_str = ""
    return output

def split(data: str,  sep: Optional[str]=None, maxsplit=math.inf):
    if sep == '':
        raise ValueError("empty separator")
    if maxsplit < 0:
        maxsplit=math.inf
    if data == '':
        return []
    if sep == None:
        return split_with_none(data, maxsplit)
    if sep == ' ':
        return split_with_space(data, maxsplit)
    data = data.lstrip()
    output = []
    split_count = 0
    data_tmp = data
    while data_tmp.find(sep) >= 0 and split_count < maxsplit:
        left, right = split_helper(data_tmp, sep)
        output.append(left)
        data_tmp = right
        split_count+=1
    output.append(data_tmp)
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #   Comparing split functionality to the built-in one
    test_string = " a b "
    assert split(test_string) == test_string.split()
    assert split(test_string, maxsplit=-1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=-1)
    assert split(test_string, " ") == test_string.split(" ")
    assert split(test_string, " ", maxsplit=-1) == test_string.split(" ", maxsplit=-1)
    test_string=''
    assert split(test_string) == test_string.split()
    assert split(test_string, maxsplit=-1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=-1)
    test_string = '       '
    assert split(test_string) == test_string.split()
    assert split(test_string, maxsplit=-1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=-1)
    test_string=',123,'
    assert split(test_string, sep=',') == test_string.split(sep=',')
    assert split(test_string, sep=',', maxsplit=-1) == test_string.split(sep=',', maxsplit=-1)
    test_string='test'
    assert split(test_string) == test_string.split()
    assert split(test_string, maxsplit=-1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=-1)
    test_string='Python    2     3'
    assert split(test_string, maxsplit=1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=1)
    assert split(test_string, maxsplit=-1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=-1)
    test_string='    test     6    7'
    assert split(test_string, maxsplit=1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=1)
    assert split(test_string, maxsplit=-1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=-1)
    test_string='    Hi     8    9'
    assert split(test_string, maxsplit=0) == test_string.split(maxsplit=0)
    assert split(test_string, maxsplit=-1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=-1)
    test_string='    set   3     4'
    assert split(test_string) == test_string.split()
    assert split(test_string, maxsplit=-1) == test_string.split(maxsplit=-1)
    test_string='set;:23'
    assert split(test_string, sep=';:', maxsplit=0) == test_string.split(sep=';:', maxsplit=0)
    test_string='set;:;:23'
    assert split(test_string, sep=';:', maxsplit=2) == test_string.split(sep=';:', maxsplit=2)
    assert split(test_string, sep=';:', maxsplit=-1) == test_string.split(sep=';:', maxsplit=-1)

Python Online

Does not seem to work correctly for split(" a b ") nor for split(" a b ", " ")

Some differences when maxsplit=-1 is passed as argument.

@trincot Updated for the cases which maxsplit < 0...

Here is another code with complexity of O(n). Even though it runs faster than the other methods provided here, it is still very slow compared to the str.split method:
def split(string, sep = None, maxsplit = -1):
  if maxsplit < 0:
    maxsplit = float('inf')
  count, i = 0, 0
  len_string = len(string)
  len_sep = 1 if sep is None else len(sep)
  result = ['']
  while i < len_string and count < maxsplit + (sep is None):
    if test := ((add := string[i]) in '\f\r\n\t\v ') and sep is None:
      add = ''
    if string[i:i+len_sep] == sep:
      result.append('')
      i += len_sep
      count += 1
      continue
    elif test:
      if not result[-1]:
        i += 1
        continue
      else:
        count += 1
        if count > maxsplit: break
        result.append('')
    result[-1] += add
    i += 1
  if sep is None and not result[-1]: result = result[:-1]
  if result: result[-1] += string[i:]
  return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
  
  a = ',123,'
  b = 'test'
  c = 'Python    2     3'
  d = '    test     6    7'
  e = '    test     6    7   '
  f = '    Hi     8    9'
  g = '    set   3     4'
  h = 'set;:23'
  i = 'set;:;:23'
  j = ' a b '
  k = ' \fbar\v\t foo\n'
  
  assert split('') == ''.split()
  assert split(a, sep=',') == a.split(',')
  assert split(b) == b.split()
  assert split(c, maxsplit=1) == c.split(maxsplit = 1)
  assert split(d, maxsplit=1) == d.split(maxsplit = 1)
  assert split(e, maxsplit=1) == e.split(maxsplit = 1)
  assert split(f, maxsplit=0) == f.split(maxsplit = 0)
  assert split(g) == g.split()
  assert split(h, sep=';:', maxsplit=0) == h.split(';:', maxsplit=0)
  assert split(i, sep=';:', maxsplit=0) == str.split(i, sep=';:', maxsplit=0)
  assert split(i, sep=';:', maxsplit=1) == str.split(i, sep=';:', maxsplit=1)
  assert split(i, sep=';:', maxsplit=2) == str.split(i, sep=';:', maxsplit=2)
  assert split(i, sep=';:', maxsplit=3) == str.split(i, sep=';:', maxsplit=3)
  assert split(i, sep=';:') == str.split(i, sep=';:')
  assert split(j, sep=' ') == str.split(j, sep=' ')
  assert split(j, sep=' ', maxsplit = 0) == str.split(j, sep=' ', maxsplit = 0)
  assert split(j, sep='a', maxsplit = 0) == str.split(j, sep='a', maxsplit = 0)
  assert split(j, sep=' a', maxsplit = 0) == str.split(j, sep=' a', maxsplit = 0)
  assert split(j, sep=' ', maxsplit = 1) == str.split(j, sep=' ', maxsplit = 1)
  assert split(j, maxsplit = 1) == str.split(j, maxsplit = 1)
  assert split(k) == str.split(k)
  


If we compare with the native method, then split(' a  b ', maxsplit=1) should return ['a', 'b '] (trailing space)

@trincot. That was an overlook.  fixed it.

Some differences when maxsplit=-1 is passed as argument.

@trincot I used maxsplit to be inf rather than -1. Note that -1is used to mean all splits, i simply used Infinity for that. One can simply useif maxsplit == -1: maxsplit = float('inf')`

How about the case "foo\nbar"

@JimmyHu you are right. Will fix that

There are several issues in your attempt, including

The function doesn't use sep
Testing for a hardcoded "," is not going to work well when it is not the separator
Appending c when it is a comma, means you are appending a comma. There is no reason to do this when the comma is the separator, nor is there good reason to do it when the comma is not the separator, so either way it is wrong.

It is nice to have test cases, and so I added a few more that test some other scenarios, like where the input string has spaces at the end, or other white-space is used, or where sep=' ' is passed as argument.
Also, when sep='', this should raise an exception.
from typing import Optional

def split_ws(data, maxsplit):
    my_list = []
    start = 0
    wantspace = True
    for i, ch in enumerate(data):
        if ch.isspace() == wantspace:
            if wantspace and start < i:
                if len(my_list) == maxsplit:
                    break
                my_list.append(data[start:i])
            start = i
            wantspace = not wantspace
    if wantspace and start < len(data):
        my_list.append(data[start:])
    return my_list

def split(data: str, sep: Optional[str]=None, maxsplit: Optional[int]=-1):
    if sep == '':
        raise ValueError("separator cannot be an empty string")
    if sep is None:
        return split_ws(data, maxsplit)
    my_list = []
    start = 0
    while len(my_list) != maxsplit:
        try:
            i = data.index(sep, start)
        except ValueError:
            break
        my_list.append(data[start:i])
        start = i + len(sep)
    my_list.append(data[start:])
    return my_list

Tests:
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    result = split(*args, **kwargs)
    expected = str.split(*args, **kwargs)
    assert result == expected, f"for '{args[0]}': expected {expected}, got {result}"
    
# Original test cases
test('')
test(',123,', sep=',')
test('test')
test('Python    2     3', maxsplit=1)
test('    test     6    7', maxsplit=1)
test('    Hi     8    9', maxsplit=0)
test('    set   3     4')
test('set;:23', sep=';:', maxsplit=0)
test('set;:;:23', sep=';:', maxsplit=2)
# Additional test cases
test('a b', maxsplit=-2)
test(' a  b ', sep=' ')
test(' c  d ')
test(' e  f ', maxsplit=-1)
test(' g  h ', maxsplit=0)
test(' i  j ', maxsplit=1)
test(' k  l ', maxsplit=2)
test('       ')
test(',,,', ',,')
test('multi\nline\r\ntext')
test('tab\tdelimited\t\tdata\t\t\t')


You have a few problem in your code, first of all as stated in the comments you are not using the sep parameter, then the maxsplit is also just used with 0 so you are probably missing something else.
And then most importantly, your assertions are very personal, why don't you compare against the existing split method ?
Here is a code snippet example that should bring you closer to your goal:
import math

def split(data: str, sep=',', maxsplit=math.inf):
    tosplit = ""
    splits = 0
    my_list = []
    for c in data:
        if c == sep and splits < maxsplit:
            my_list.append(tosplit)
            splits += 1
            tosplit = ""
        else:
            tosplit += c
    my_list.append(tosplit)
    return my_list

But you have to see your assertions again because they probably won't work with the str.split method neither.
Edit:
Here follows a version that should work with multi-character separators. Instead of just looking at characters one by one, you look for them in batch of len(sep).
import math
def split(data: str, sep=None, maxsplit=math.inf):
    tosplit = ""
    splits = 0
    my_list = []
    sep_length = len(sep) if sep else 1
    i = 0
    while i < len(data):
        if data[i:i+sep_length] == sep and splits < maxsplit:
            my_list.append(tosplit)
            splits += 1
            tosplit = ""
            i += sep_length
        else:
            tosplit += data[i]
            i += 1
    my_list.append(tosplit)
    return my_list


This doesn't work with multi-character separators…

Yes you are right, lemme think about that, at least it can help him get closer to a working solution meanwhile

@Joachim Huet > c == sep, maybe it is better to use string.find method

@JimmyHu Well it would work but probably he can't use any of the str methods, I will edit with a while loop and see if it works

The default separator for python split is a run of (any) consecutive whitespace characters.

At the time of writing this implementation only passes 3 out of the 9 tests that the asker has provided.
